# Move an object on the edge of an ellipse

Tags: java, c++, math

I have some drawing problem.

I represent an object with an X and a Y coordinate. I would like to move this object around on the edge of an ellipse (a circle). What i would like to know, is the method, what i need to do with theese X and Y values in every update, to look like a circular movement.

I hope it's not a duplicate (I tried every keyword, what i could think of). Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [*parametric* equations for an ellipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#General_parametric_form) centred at the origin are:

```
x = A * cos(t)
y = B * sin(t)
```

So on every frame, you plug the current value of `t` into those equations, and you get the required coordinates.

Comment: +1 -- but dot notation for multiplication is possibly confusing in a question tagged C++ and Java...

Comment: Thank you, but could you please explain a bit more detailed, what A, B and t are?

Comment: @bali182: `A` and `B` are the radii of the ellipse in the x-dimension and y-dimension, respectively.  `t` is the current time.

Comment: Well, i dont know, what kind of sorcery is this, but it certainly works. Thanks again :)