# How do you create a modded ellipse path with sin/cos

Tags: java, math

I am trying to figure out how I can mod the formula for moving on an elliptical path that has more rounded out edges like in the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZnOI.jpg

I have seen this post: [Move an object on the edge of an ellipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556063/move-an-object-on-the-edge-of-an-ellipse)

Comment: what you are showing looks more like rectangle with rounded edges, than an ellipse with rounded edges. Are you sure rectangle won't suit your needs?

Comment: I really over exaggerated in the drawing to make my point. I think i am better off with a more rounded out ellipse if possible.

Comment: Rounded out ellipse is a circle. I think you mean you want ellipse to be closer to a rectangle, but rectangle with rounded corners is not suitable for you, right?

Comment: I think the super ellipses is what I have been looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are [super ellipses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse) something you like?

[image]

Comment: Would you know how to write that out in java?

Comment: @InexHead Use `Math.abs(x)` for "Abs[x]", `Math.signum(x)` for "Sign[x]", and `Math.pow(x, y)` to compute the power x^y.

Comment: That was it, you rock!