# How does one get smooth movement around a super ellipses?

Tags: java, math

I wrote a question and got an answer about how to create super ellipses ([How do you create a modded ellipse path with sin/cos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39797192/how-do-you-create-a-modded-ellipse-path-with-sin-cos)), it works great but I am running into one issue. In the image below I have two super ellipse I construct based on an alpha change of 0.01. You can see that at the quarter points of the ellipses there is noticeably more space between points than in other areas. This is causing my movement to "jump" at those spots. Is there a way for me to make it so those gaps are non existent or maybe add a piece of math to help hid the issue?

[image: 2 super ellipses]

Comment: do you know how bezier curves work?

Comment: I have not heard of that.

Comment: it is a way of describing curve path with points. I suggest you read on it, in your case using 3 successive points (1 point + 2 control points) you can get a very smooth interpolation of your complete curve.

Comment: I will do some research on it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the best way for me to get the smooth movement was to use the super ellipses equation to build a list of path nodes and then move through the list with a constant speed variable.